# PHP Facebook Plugin

Tags: php, facebook

I do have website for Hotel which has facebook registration module for the users to register. There are two kinds of user for my website, one is normal registered user and second user is Facebook Registered user. This seems to work correctly upto this moment.In the website, the users are allowed to post their own review about hotels,favorites etc.

I need a way for automatic sharing of reviews, likes and favourites to the users Facebook friends in the Facebook website.Is there is any php-Facebook plugin to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at fb php-skd [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)

You can do most of facebook interaction using this sdk or calling the public Graph API ([here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)) via php-curl :)

If you need more help please post what you exactly need

If you need to post on friends'wall you must do it with the old REST API (method [stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/)). For instance, you need to do something like that (suppose you have already get your friends' ids:

```
$url = "https://https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish
$params = array(
    "access_token" => 'the access token for the user posting the review"
    "message"      => 'An example message'
    "target_id"    => 'user A friend's id'
    "uid"          =>  'user A ID' 
....more option here, see stream.publish docs
);
$ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);        
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $returnValue = curl_exec($ch);
```

I didn't tried the above code but it should work.
You can obtain a list of user A friends list by do something like that;

```
$access_token = 'the access token for the user posting the review";
$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$access_token;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $returnValue = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

the above code return (in $returnValue) a JSON encoded string containing pairs of username and user ID of "user A" friends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Whenever the users in the site write reviews about the product, then this review need to be automatically updated to the user Facebook friends (Facebook Area). So they get alert about the product and will go into the website.This is main idea to implement in my website.If you could ,please provide me any working sample using this criteria or any reference links with appropriate procedures.

Comment: If you want to write on someone's wall you need his permission to do that. (actually, when the user log-in with facebook he need to grant your application the "publish_stream" permission). I'm sorry, but I  didn't exactly understand what do you mean with "the review must me automatically updated to the user Facebook friend" can u please make us  an example so we can understand better? I make a guess: User A reviews hotel H, then user B add a new review to the same hotel and you want user A t be notificated somehow about the new review?" Tell me if I missed the point and I can help you better:P

Comment: Ok mate thanks.Me too sorry for my english.I think you are right. Let me explain more detailed way. If the USER A write some reviews about the Hotel H, then this review needs to be updated automatically to the Facebook Friends(Like B,C,D,E etc) of USER A.Similarly if the User B likes some product that also need to be updated to all of his own Facebook Friends.So for each user write new (review,likes,favourites) these things need to be automatically updated to his Facebook Friends.If you do need more explanation please let me know i can explain you in more detailed way.

Comment: I've added some examples using php-curl. You must use the old rest api for this behaviour. I'm not sure but I think you can get the friend list using the "read_stream" permission on user A (must check this :D )

Comment: Thanks for your examples.Let me play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use their graph API.
Facebook has a PHP SDK for easier integration. They have more-or-less good documentation for their API, have a read-through at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/, specifically http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

Edit: oops, not fast enough.

Comment: I wouldn't say that, although I haven't seen much besides the auth and graph API. My main problem with it was that it's hard to get an overview of all the different parts, but I was fine with the technical part of it up till now.

Answer (score 0):

**go to this link where to you will get facebook sdk for javascript and follow the steps that are given in website**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/